# What does require('..') mean?

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js and have been trying to test some code using yarn. At the moment I am using the following code:

```
const assert = require('assert')
const username = process.env.HDFS_USERNAME || 'webuser'
const endpoint1 = process.env.HDFS_NAMENODE_1 || 'namenode1.lan'
const endpoint2 = process.env.HDFS_NAMENODE_2 || 'namenode2.lan'
const homeDir = `/user/${username}`
const basePath = process.env.HDFS_BASE_PATH || homeDir
const nodeOneBase = `http://${endpoint1}:9870`
const nodeTwoBase = `http://${endpoint2}:9870`

const webhdfs = require('..')

const should = require('should')
const nock = require('nock')

describe('WebHDFSClient', function () {

  const oneNodeClient = new (require('..')).WebHDFSClient({
    namenode_host: endpoint1
  });
})
```

that I've got from this repo:

https://github.com/ryancole/node-webhdfs/blob/master/test/webhdfs.js

and when I try to run `yarn test` I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module '..'
Require stack:
- myrepo/test/lib/hdfs.js
- myrepo/test/tests.js
- myrepo/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js
- myrepo/node_modules/mocha/index.js
- myrepo/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha
  Error: Cannot find module '..'
```

As you can see, `require('..')` is used couple of times in the code and I can not figure out what it means. I've found posts on `require('../')` which I think is not exactly the same as this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inbuilt node.js `require` function uses a quite complex package resolution algorithm. So there are lots of things that may influence it.

#### A. Defaulting to `index.js`

node.js implicitly requires a file named `index.js` if no file name is specified.

So `require("..")` translates to `require("../index.js")`

#### B. The `main` package property.

If you `require` is inside a module and points to the root of the module it will read the `main` property from the packages `package.json` and require the file specified there.

So given this package definition (`package.json`)

```
{
    "main": "./fileA.js"
}
```

The call to `require("..")` will be translated to `require("../fileA.js")`

#### Resources

[Good explanatory blog entry](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm)

[Official Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

Comment: I don't think it is the same as `require("../")` based on what I've read here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-self but I might be wrong. What surprises me is how it is in this line of code: `const oneNodeClient = new (require('..')).WebHDFSClient({`

Comment: @ahajib That package has very little to do with this question, since you require a module from inside `node_modules`. What supprises you about that line?

Comment: Your updated response makes more sense to me. Thanks